# I am experiencing issues when trying to transfer funds on the Polygon mainnet

Tags: tokens, transfer

When I use the **Polygon** **testnet** to `transfer tokens`, it works fine. However, when I use the **mainnet**, an error occurs. Upon checking the `contract methods` on the **mainnet**, I notice that it lacks `transfer` or `decimals`. How can I execute token transfers if the smart contract does not have these methods

```
const axios = require('axios');
const Web3 = require('web3');



async function getDecimalsContract(chain, tokenAddress) {

  var path = `https://api.polygonscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${tokenAddress}&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY`;
  var web3 = new Web3('https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com');

  if (chain == 'testnet')
    web3 = new Web3('https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com');
  path = `https://api-testnet.polygonscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${tokenAddress}&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY`;


  const response = await axios.get(`${path}/token/${tokenAddress}`);

  if (response.status === 200) {
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(response.data.result), tokenAddress);
    console.log(contract.methods)
  }

}
//testnet:0xF4e98ed7DdB22a2C19e26395aB7dA414654754Cb
getDecimalsContract('mainnet', '0x3c499c542cEF5E3811e1192ce70d8cC03d5c3359')//USDC
//When I retrieve the methods available in the smart contract on the testnet.:
/* {
  name: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x06fdde03': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'name()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  totalSupply: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x18160ddd': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'totalSupply()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  decimals: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x313ce567': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'decimals()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  balanceOf: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x70a08231': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'balanceOf(address)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  symbol: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x95d89b41': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'symbol()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  transfer: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0xa9059cbb': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'transfer(address,uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
} */
//When I retrieve the methods available in the smart contract on the meinnet.: 

/* {
  admin: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0xf851a440': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'admin()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  changeAdmin: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x8f283970': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'changeAdmin(address)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  implementation: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x5c60da1b': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'implementation()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  upgradeTo: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x3659cfe6': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'upgradeTo(address)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  upgradeToAndCall: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0x4f1ef286': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'upgradeToAndCall(address,bytes)': [Function: bound _createTxObject]
} */
```

Comment: Please share the contract code, it's difficult to determine the issue without looking at the code.

Comment: I have added the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code seems like this is a proxy.(Please share the mainnet and testnet address for confirmation).

If it is a proxy, then you need to call the implementation's functions on the proxy address.

The way it works is:

Create a contract instance of the implementation contract on the proxy address, using web3.Contract(). Then call the desired function.

This way you are calling the methods from the implementation contract on the proxy address. This might be confusing if you are not aware of how the upgradeable Proxies work.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, when I retrieve information from the contract, in the methods of the main network, it does not include methods such as 'transfer,' 'decimals,' etc. If they are not available, how can I transfer tokens?

Comment: He just answered your question. You don't need to call the functions of the proxy but the functions of the implementation on the proxy address.